# Neo4j: Java API IndexHits<Node>.size() is 0

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to use the Java API for Neo4j but I seem to be stuck at IndexHits. If I query the DB with Cypher using

```
START n=node:types(type="Process") RETURN n;
```

I get all 2087 nodes of type "Process".

In my application I have the following lines

```
Index<Node> nodeIndex = db.index().forNodes("types");
IndexHits<Node> hits = nodeIndex.get("type", "Process");
System.out.println("Node index size: " + hits.size());
```

which leads my console to spit out a value of 0. Here, db is of course an instance of `GraphDatabaseService`.

I expected an object that included all 2087 nodes. What am I doing wrong?

The `.size()` question is just the prelude to my iterator

```
 for(Node process : hits) { ... }
```

but that does not much when hits.size() == 0. According to http://api.neo4j.org/1.9.2/org/neo4j/graphdb/index/IndexHits.html this should be possible, provided there is something in `hits`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens if you iterate over the results and increment a counter to get the size?

Comment: I iterated like this `for (Node process : hits) {++resultCount;} and I got 0.

Comment: Is it possible to share your graph.db folder?

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't be possible. Is there anything I need to look for?

Comment: Oh, and before I attempt to iterate through `hits` I check the following: `if(db.index().existsForNodes("types"))`, and it evaluates to `true`, so there is indeed an index.

Comment: Furthermore, I tried `Iterable<Node> nodes = GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllNodes();
   
  for (Node node : nodes)
  {
   System.out.println(node.toString());
  }` and got only Node[0] as output. I have no idea why I have an almost empty graph when in the web interface I have my graph with a few thousand nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Man, I feel so embarrassed...

It so happens that I had set up the DB_PATH to my default data folder, whereas the default storage folder is the default data folder plus graph.db. When I tried to run the code from that corrected DB_PATH I got an error saying that a lock file was in place because the Neo4j server was running. After shutting it down it worked perfectly.

So, if you happen to see the following error, just stop the server and run the code again:

`Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Could not create lock file
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)`

I found on several forums that you cannot run the Neo4j server and use the Java API to query it at the same time.